# globalize3 configuration I18n.locale variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize3

take a look into my model and my migration

i only have one attribute to test the globalize3 gem

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   translates :name
end
```

my migration looks like the following

```
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
    Car.create_translation_table! :name => :string
  end

  def down
    Car.drop_translation_table!
    drop_table :cars
  end
end
```

and i got the following error while trying to save new car details with the attribute name

**ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: locale**

i think i am missing some declaration/configuration for globalize3 to access the I18n.locale variable.

btw i am using rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3p125

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just found an workaround to my problem by following this [Issue](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/128)

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  translates :name
  class Translation
    attr_accessible :locale
  end
end
```

Comment: the only solution I've found for rails 4

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be like:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :translations_attributes
  translates :name
end
```

See:

[Rails 3.2.3: How to mass assign associated models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147198/rails-3-2-3-how-to-mass-assign-associated-models)