# Rails 3.2.3: How to mass assign associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails 3.2.3, I have a form with two nested models, when I try to submit the form, I get this error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ExperimentsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: descriptions_attributes, circuits_attributes
```

Here is my models:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :intro_text

  has_many :circuits, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :descriptions, :dependent => :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :descriptions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:data].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :circuits, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:data].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Circuit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :data, :title

  belongs_to :experiment
end

class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :data, :title

  belongs_to :experiment
end
```

I can add `attr_accessible` for a field, but, what about the nested models ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :intro_text, :descriptions_attributes, :circuits_attributes
  [...]
```

In you experiment model.